# Using a single html template for Rail view and Angular Template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, route-provider

I have a Ruby on Rails app that loads a single page Angular JS Web App when the user is logged in, and serves static info pages via RoR views when the user is not logged in.

The angular templates are in 'app/assets/templates/' and the rails files are in 'app/views'.

I have a text heavy html page that I would like re-use with both rails and angular. I've tried accessing the rails view from my angular $routeProvider, setting templateURL to the path of the view. This causes more than one instance of angular to load and it gets stuck in a loop.

```
    app.config ($routeProvider) ->
      $routeProvider.when('/features/',
        templateUrl: '/views/features.html'
      )
```

I've tried rendering the file in my assets/templates folder through a rails view. That doesn't work either since rails can't find the partial.

```
    = render 'assets/templates/features.html'
```

Does anyone know how I might be able to use a single template for both?

Answer (score 0):

I'm mot sure what exactly you mean by text heavy page. But what about other solution - extract all text to JSON file with keys (some sort of translation file). For example:

```
{ "title1": "Title", "paragraph1": "lore up sum. .." }
```

Then you can load this JSON in your rails controller and pass it to view that render text parts from it.

```
<h1><%= @text ['title1'] %></h1>
<p><%= @text['paragraph1'] %></p>
```

And as well load JSON as resource in your angular app and pass it to view.

```
<h1>{{ text.title1 }}</h1>
<p>{{ text.paragraph1 }}</p>
```

If your text is somehow structured you can make use if it and automate the view with loops, conditions etc and so save repeated parts even more.